# Ansible with_items conditional check against json

Tags: json, windows, ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I am trying to write a playbook which checks for the windows features installed. If they are installed, it should skip them, otherwise install them from my list of vars.

```
- name: win command
  win_command: 'powershell.exe "Get-WindowsFeature | Where Installed | Select -exp Name | ConvertTo-Json"'
  register: result

- name: Register vars
  set_fact:
    featureinstalled: '{{ result.stdout | from_json }}'

- name: Installing features
  win_feature:
    name: '{{ item }}'
    state: Present
  with_items:
    '{{features_to_install}}'
  when: '{{ item }} != {{ featureinstalled }}'
```

My features_to_install vars in a separate /vars/ file:

```
---
features_to_install: [FileAndStorage-Services,File-Services,.....]
```

I want the playbook to skip installing the feature if the feature is present in the JSON. The error Im getting:

> {  "failed": true, 
>       "msg": "The conditional check '{{ item }} != {{ featureinstalled }}' failed. The error was: template error while templating string:
>   expected token ',', got 'string'. String: {% if
>   FileAndStorage-Services != [u'FileAndStorage-Services',
>   u'Storage-Services', u'FS-SMB1', u'WoW64-Support'] %} True {% else %}
>   False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to have been in
>   '/tmp/worldengine/src/roles/webserver/tasks/windows_features.yml':
>   line 31, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the
>   exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n-
>   name: Installing features\n  ^

Comment: How about reading the [docs on `when`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement) before writing the code? Also, `!=` operator is blatantly wrong - "not equal" is not what you intend to check - say the expression aloud in human language and you'll figure it out.

Comment: lol that worked

Answer (score 0):

There are [handy filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) available to manipulate sets:

```
- name: Installing features
  win_feature:
    name: '{{ item }}'
    state: Present
  with_items: '{{ features_to_install | difference(featureinstalled) }}'
```

This will iterate over features from `features_to_install` list, but that are not in `featureinstalled` list.

Comment: Awesome thanks for this. My conditional check in when was wrong. I ended up using "in" and "not in", however I will test out your approach as well. Thanks!